# How to aggregate array values in surrealdb?

Tags: surrealdb

Using the SurrealDB select statement, how would one aggregate all the array values from all the records of the 'program' field into a single array with unique values?
The answer should look like this:

```
program: ['flights','apps','entertainment']
```

Using the following data set with two records:

```
[
    {
        email: 'jan@test3.co.za',
        firstname: 'Jan',
        id: person:0b3b952c565155fcb0ae9acfedf99315,
        lastname: 'Morkel',
        program: [
            'flights',
            'apps'
        ]
    },
    {
        email: 'sam@test3.co.za',
        firstname: 'Sam',
        id: person:8bc35665018b595b95bd9b2e909ed651,
        lastname: 'pedlar',
        program: [
            'entertainment',
            'flights'
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is called person for instance, you can try the following:

```
SELECT array::group(program) FROM person GROUP ALL;
```

See this related GitHub Issue: https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/issues/2133

Comment: This select statement gives the following error:
There was a problem with the database: There was an error processing a remote HTTP request
I tried:
SELECT array::group(program) as program FROM person GROUP program
But this then gives 
{
    [
        program: [
            'flights',
            'apps'
        ]
    ]
},
{
    [
        program: [
           'entertainment',
            'flights'
        ]
    ]
}

Comment: Please try SELECT array::group(program) FROM person GROUP ALL; as mentioned in the Github Issue linked above. Hope this helps!

Comment: FYI `GROUP ALL` was added in beta10